# What verb used when one's words change something in the future to bad (not directly but somehow mystically)?

Tags: single-word-requests

What verb used when one's words change something in the future to negative (not directly but somehow mystically)? For example you expect something positive in the future and another person tells you about it and in the future you get something negative and you blame him/her for that word just like they changed the result from positive to negative. Google translate gives these three words:
to overlook
to witch
to bedevil

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it looks like you're describing this kind of situation:

> Person A: "Look at him go. Just one more time and he'll have a perfect score."
>
> (He fails the last time.)
>
> Person B: "You **jinxed** him!"

Or:

> "Ssh! Don't say it. If you do, you'll **jinx** it."

---

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [jinx](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jinx#h2):

> : to foredoom to failure or misfortune : bring bad luck to

---

Sometimes, people will start to talk about something but then, literally, ["knock on wood"](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/knock-on-wood.html) (or "tap wood") to prevent its mention from jinxing it (bringing it bad luck).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's it. I also wanted to mention about the "knocking on wood" but you were first.